# Two golang template files but only one is getting rendered

Tags: html, go

I have this golange file which is using echo framework. it uses html/template with go:embed. When I'm opening the index route "/", it's rendering the content of about.html. I don't know how to fix this.

```golang
package main
​
import (
    "embed"
    "html/template"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
​
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)
​
var (
    //go:embed templates/*.html
    templateFS embed.FS
)
​
type Template struct {
    templates *template.Template
}
​
func (t *Template) Render(w io.Writer, name string, data interface{}, c echo.Context) error {
    return t.templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, name, data)
}
​
func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    e.Renderer = &Template{
        templates: template.Must(template.ParseFS(templateFS, "templates/*.html")),
    }
​
    e.GET("/about", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "about.html", "")
    })
​
    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "index.html", "")
    })
​
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":" + os.Getenv("PORT")))
}
```

The base.html, about.html and index.html are as below:

// base.html

```html
{{define "base"}}
<main class="container">
   {{template "content" }}
</main>
{{end}}
```

// about.html

```html
{{template "base"}}
{{define "content"}}
  <h1>I am about</h1>
{{end}}
```

// index.html

```html
{{template "base"}}
{{define "content"}}
  <h1>I am index</h1>
{{end}}
```

Comment: You can't have two templates with the same name in the same `*template.Template` object.

Comment: Try making `{end}}` -> `{{end}}` in `Index.html`?

Comment: It was a typo, fixed it but not getting expected result.